# Reshape dataframe using pandas/numpy in a particular manner - convert multiple columns into two

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy

Given the following data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        x1=["zero", "one", "two"],
        x2=["three", "four", "five"],
        x3=["six", "seven", "eight"],
        x4=["nine", "ten", "eleven"],
    )
)
```

which looks as:

```py
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
     x1     x2     x3      x4
0  zero  three    six    nine
1   one   four  seven     ten
2   two   five  eight  eleven
```

I would like to reshape it to the following

```
x1      x2
zero    three
one     four
two     five
three   six
four    seven
five    eight
six     nine
seven   ten
eight   eleven
```

The following works, but I do not thing the approach is sound:

```py
c1 = df.columns[: df.shape[1] - 1]
c2 = df.columns[1:]
d1 = df.loc[:, c1].T.values.flatten()
d2 = df.loc[:, c2].T.values.flatten()
pd.DataFrame(dict(x1=d1, x2=d2))
```

Comment: Reshape like that is easy with a numpy array, for example the `df.values` one.

Comment: @hpaulj feel free to add an example I'd be interested to see it

Comment: Since you are taking overlapping ranges of columns, I can't do any better than you,  `d1 = df.values[:,:-1].ravel(order='F')` and `d2=df.values[:,1:].ravel(order='F')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`np.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) slicing in a list comprehension:

```
df_new = (pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.iloc[:,i:i+2].to_numpy()
                                   for i in range(df.shape[1]-1)]),
                      columns=['x1', 'x2']))
```

[out]

```
      x1      x2
0   zero   three
1    one    four
2    two    five
3  three     six
4   four   seven
5   five   eight
6    six    nine
7  seven     ten
8  eight  eleven
```

Comment: that's great - this is how I initially considered things (with `i+2`), but with for loops instead of using numpy/pandas methods (so it was poor). I've not used `vstack` before, but it looks handy. Thanks